# Aptana Studio:: Un-Indent block of code

Tags: ide, formatting, aptana, indentation, aptana3

I am using Aptana Studio for Mac and would like to know how I can select a block of code and remove the indentation/whitespace. I know you can select a block of code and hit the tab button to indent it, but I need to do the reverse of that if it makes sense.

Example: This:

```
    if() {
        if(){

        }
    }
```

Becomes This:

```
if() {
    if(){

    }
}
```

Comment: Does Shift + Tab work?

Comment: Yep works wonderfully thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is posted in the comments thanks to @pallandt

Shift + Tab

Answer (score 0):

When multiple lines are selected, <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Shift-Tab</kbd> indent and dedent these lines.

When nothing is selected, <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Shift-Tab</kbd> insert or remove whitespace to align the cursor on a tab boundary.